# How can I reinforce that security questions answers should not be the same and how to encrypt?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4

When my users are creating an account they need to fill and set several security questions pertaining to their account. I am wondering, how can I make sure that the answer the user enters for each security question is not the same as an answer for a different question? What's the proper attribute for it?

Also, for the security question answers, should I encrypt the answers so that whoever is sniffing the network won't see the answers? How? What should I look into or lookup for this approach?

Comment: After a user has completed his registration, in what circumstances do you ask those security questions and what do you do if they are all answered correctly?

Comment: Those security questions will only get asked if they forgot their password and if they're answered correctly, then they get emailed a unique link to type in old password, new password and confirm password.

Comment: So if they forget their password, they get emailed a link to type in *their old password*? I don't think you've really thought this one through properly...

Comment: Sorry I mean new password, confirm password!

Comment: You should treat the answers just like you treat the password: hash with a secure hash designed for passwords such as scrypt or bcrypt. You should also deploy SSL, otherwise you open up your users to every kind of MiTM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are making a standard web app, then TLS is your only "safe" method of protecting users from MitM attacks and traffic sniffing. Take a look at ipviking's map of real time cyber attacks; a large number come from China because encryption is largely outlawed and browser requests can get hijacked. (Most infosec guys I know agree that X.509 is broken, the IETF is compromised, TLS is likely weakened intentionally by the NSA ([kinda like this](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_EC_DRBG)), and the entire key spaces for RSA and elliptic curves are being precomputed by governments. Nevertheless, it is still better than unencrypted traffic.)

If you must use security questions, I suggest putting everything in lowercase, stripping out whitespace, and hashing with a random salt stored along side it (it could be a single salt stored as part of a user record). I suggest at least 256 bit hash and 100 rounds (fewer if hash algorithm is already slow). Bcrypt hashes are also quite good because they involve encrypting a hash and storing the salt as part of the hash string.

If not using bcrypt, then be sure to not use a simple `str1==str2` boolean for checking the answer; you should use something like the following, which will avoid the string comparison side channel attack.

```
function compHashes ($h1, $h2) {
    $r = 0;
    if (strlen($h1) !== strlen($h2)) return false;
    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($h1); ++$i)
        $r |= ord($h1[$i])^ord($h2[$i]);
    return $r == 0;
}
```

The considerations for binary apps are a little different in that you can hard code or bundle a public key (or several) and use NaCl to generate client private keys and handle handshakes and encryption between server and client. There are libraries in every compilable language for this, and writing a wrapper for a statically linked library is not too difficult if that is the route you choose. Rolling your own crypto is definitely not recommended if you are not very familiar with cryptography and infosec matters.

Comment: I wrote the code example in PHP because I was half asleep and did not see the C# and asp.net tags. Consider it pseudocode ;)

Comment: Nice summary. Can't believe you were half asleep ;-)

Comment: @JonathanVoss, it's close enough to C#. Needs some brackets and removal of $. However, what is ord()?

Comment: ord returns the ASCII value of a char, so `ord('a')^ord('a')` is 97 xor 97. [Here's the php manual explanation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php).

Answer (score 1):

can't you just compare the strings the user enters?

To prevent sniffing, you have to encrypt the answers on the client, pass your server's public key to the client and use it to encrypt them before passing them back to the server. Alternatively, just use SSL comms.

Comment: okay thank you. What should I look up for encrypting answers and passwords on client and server? Like terminology? So that I can read up on it? Thanks!

Comment: If you have to ask, just stick to using https for your site.

Comment: Encryption alone is not good enough. Password/Secret Answers should also be hashed. https://danielmiessler.com/study/encoding_encryption_hashing/

Comment: BTW, assuming the OP understands how to store the answers in the backend, this is the answer that is most relevant to the actual question. Since it clearly tells what the OP needs to do: compare answers and SSL for securing transfer.

Answer (score 1):

Security questions are useless. They do not add security but annoy the hell out of the users. Do what serious companies do and verify identity via cell phone or just send a password reset link to the associated email (case in point: Stack Exchange).

Comment: Although I completely agree on the useless character of security questions (actually, I consider them not only useless, but dangerous and extremely annoying), this doesn't answer the question. Also, Yahoo, Microsoft and Facebook are some of the many companies which use security questions and may possibly qualify as “serious companies”.

Comment: I second what @MainMa said above. Completely agree about the ineffectiveness of security questions. However, serious companies do need to have a "recovery" mechanism not just based on email address alone. Email accounts get hacked every day and access to email does not guarantee ownership of the account. All I am saying is that you need an alternate recovery system (phone???)

Comment: I don't have any "Security" questions on my FB or Yahoo accounts AFAIK. And I think they both are now capable of using a phone for password recovery. It's arguable whether Yahoo is still a serious company.

Comment: FB uses a phone to send you a recovery password so they can tie your phone number to your FB account and data-mine you even further :-)